# One page checkout continue button not working both guest and registered

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting the following javaScript error on the checkout page:

```
js.js:667 Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

At first I thought conflict but I'm pretty sure the order of script loading is correct - i.e. jQuery, noconflict, then prototype. Is this right?

I then realised my host had upgraded PHP to 5.6.17, so will try older versions tomorrow when I have time to re-configure the PHP Handler etc. But I think this is unlikely due to timing.

The Magento CE is 1.9.0.1 and PHP 5.6.17.

The issue is compounded by the fact that the setup is Joomla connected to Magento with Yireo's Magebridge.

Comment: Maybe my answer here can help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86474/408

Comment: thanks @simonthesorcerer. No errors are being logged in system.log or exception.log and I changed the directory permissions to 777. Looking at the network tab in chrome developer tools, the savebilling action posts and receives a valid JSON response. Then getadditional posts and the response looks valid? `<script type="text/javascript">function x9b19e(className) {var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);while(elements.length > 0){elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);}}x9b19e("ba188");</script>`.

Comment: I've tried PHP versions 5.4,5.5 and 5.6, same problem. Also changed the order of the JS files to 1. prototype, 2. jQuery, 3. noconflict. No good :(

Comment: I'd also check what "element" is exactly when the  error is thrown. The developer console gives a stacktrace if it is open when the error occurs; maybe "element" points to an ID that does not exist due to a non-standard checkout or sth else?

Comment: element = "domready" set by a preceding function in mootools-core.js. If you could take a look I'd be eternally grateful as I really don't know how to proceed https://footactive.co.uk/magento-root/checkout/onepage/

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird JS-function in your response.

This function `x9b19e()` is definitely not Magento standard. It will most likely be added by a 3rd party module or a malicious script that has infected your webhost.

It seems to be appended to every request to your server, and so it is also appended to the response received by the AJAX-request to `/checkout/onepage/saveBilling`. This response should be a valid JSON-string, and it would be one if not for the JS-snippet at the end.

If you have SSH-access to your server, you can find this snippet by doing `grep -r "x9b19e" ./` in the Magento root directory. Find out why someone thinks it should be there, and either remove it or limit its use to the places where it is necessary.

**UPDATE**

Either the function is somewhere in one of the Joomla-extensions, in a malicious script or in one of the Magento-extensions (I don't know how MageBridge works, and if some of them are loaded when the Joomla-homepage is rendered). If you can't find it with `grep`, it could be that the code is generated or base64-decoded/-encoded at runtime.

I would start with checking the `index.php`-files for strange code, then disabling all Joomla-extensions one after the other and check after each one if the script is still there, then `diff` my Joomla-installation with a fresh download, then disable the Magento-extensions in the same manner like the Joomla extensions.

Comment: Wow, thanks man :) I ran the command and it doesn't find anything though?

Comment: I took another look and noticed that the script is also on you start page, so maybe you should `grep` your Joomla installation as well; If you don't find the snippet there: if you make a simple file test.html in your webroot and visit it in the browser, is the `<script...` at its bottom then?

Comment: I did run grep on the joomla installation as well but it's not found. And created test.html as you said and it's empty

Comment: I ran `grep -r "x9b19e" ./`on the home directory and got this: `./virtfs/XXXXX/var/log/dcpumon/toplog.1465822201: 7185 root      20   0  219m 119m  744 R 68.8  0.4   0:08.57 grep -r x9b19e.` There were more results after this as well. Is that just a log of my search?

Comment: Yes, imho. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I started disabling joomla extensions and now every page of the site is the snippet only :( So restoring from a backup

Comment: I see now it's gone, what happened? :)

Comment: I checked the index.php files, which didn't contain any suspicious code. Then I started disabling Joomla extensions and checking the home page for the snippet after each one. I got to about ten and decided to disable them all, intending to enable them one by one. But this broke the site and every page, apart from the Magento side was blank with only the snippet in the source. Certainly seems like infection?

Comment: Before restoring from backup I checked the extensions in phpmyadmin and they were all enabled, even though I had disabled them all! At which point I had a little cry and proceeded to start the restore lol. Thanks for your help Simon I really do appreciate it :)