# Redirect to Cart page instead of payment page while checkout in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-gateway

While checkout in Magento, after providing `checkout method, Billing information, Shipping information,Shipping method, Payment information` the site is redirecting to cart page.

That is in Payment information section we can select the payment gateway (here either paytm or ccavenue), after selecting any payment gateway option the **site is redirect to cart page instead of payment page.**

**EDIT**

When I click continue button after selecting the payment gate way(paytm or ccavenue) I got error in console:

```
...checkout/onepage/savePayment/  500 Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be multiple reasons that may cause this issue. But with the given details, it won't be possible to point to the exact reason. So we need you to debug your site more.

For that, use [**this link**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86474/3535) and update your question with more details of the error. Then we would able to help you to resolve your issue.

In short,

1. Turn on debug mode and enable error logging in Magento. This will throw errors in `var\log` directory.
2. While you are doing check out, turn on your browser console. Under 'Network' section, you would be able to see the ajax requests happening in the background and most probably you will see the full error trace there.

### EDIT

As you can see in the error log, the third party module `Relishly_Search` is what makes trouble here. You need to go to the specified files and resolve the issues reported.

Comment: ` var\log\system.log`  not giving any error related to this. But gives error (1 warning and 1 notice) regarding to a plugin already installed. `2017-08-22T04:34:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /home/myproject/public_html/myproject.com/bf/app/code/community/Relishly/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 118
2017-08-22T04:34:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/myproject/public_html/myproject.com/bf/app/code/community/Relishly/Search/Model/Rewrite/Catalogsearch/Layer/Filter/Category.php on line 29`. Is this cause the issue?

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: WORKED...Thanks for your replay..I uninstalled the plugin `Relishly_Search` and checked the process..Its working..Thank you very much Rajeev..