# Place order: Error processing your order, please try again later

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, onepage-checkout

I need help when I click on place order I have this popup `"Error processing your order, please try again later."`
I don't know why I'm using a module [`onepagecheckout`](https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/iwd_opc)

This var system.log & console.log & my interface.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you In advance.

Comment: maybe my answer here can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86466/onepage-checkout-returns-500/86474#86474

Comment: thank you but error is still dispaly

Comment: what *is* the error?

Comment: Error processing your order, please try again later and in my console show Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Session Expired)

Comment: (1) "Error processing your order" is the user-readable nice error message that Magento generates for the frontend; you need to know the real error on the server side / in the code. In the answer linked above, it's described how to find it. (2) I don't know how to handle the 403, but a Google search for "403 session expired magento" returns a lot of results

Comment: my var/log show me  that HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home1/belghiti/chamsse.ma/BETA/chems/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52  how i can slove this problem ? thank you

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673376/1130898